# Trying to get FadeIn onClick to work jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to jQuery and I'm having troubles on getting this function to work. So I'm making a bio page where everytime you click on a name, their name and description fade in. I'm not sure if my code is right or targeting the right thing or my placement of the code is right.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$("#bios a").click(function (event) {

   event.preventDefault();

   $("#description").fadeIn('slow');

   var links = $(this).attr("href");

   $("#bio").load(links + " #description");

});

});
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the corresponding HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
<div class="bios">
<a href=""><div class="description">Some Name</div></a>
<a href=""><div class="description">Some Other name</div></a>
</div>
```

And you can use `$(this)`, which refers to the active element.

```
$("#bios a").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
$(this).find('.description').fadeIn()
})
```